why does datetime is automatically changed to string in sql query
why does datetime is automatically changed to string in sql query
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE order_date = '2024-01-01 00:00:00' AND total_amount > 500;
if date time is stored in number format why do we need to write it as a string in query
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE order_date = '2024-01-01 00:00:00' AND total_amount > 500;

if date time is stored in number format Datetime value is stored in DATETIME format which is not "number format". why do we need to write it as a string in query You should not confuse the value and its output.

MySQL recognizes Datetime literals in a few different formats:
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date = '2024-01-01 00:00:00' ...

SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date = '20240101000000' ...

SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date = 20240101000000 ...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/date-and-time-literals.html
The reason it's good to support datetime values as strings is that it's harder for humans to read the binary bytes used to store the value.
Also the binary bytes for storage depends on the implementation of the storage engine and the version of MySQL. Using a string makes the value independent of those implementations.
And finally, because the SQL standard requires it.
